# NPM peer dependency conflict

Tags: npm, npm-install, peer-dependencies

I have `my-package` that has `@angular/common@"^12.2.6"` as peer dependency and root project that also has `@angular/common@"^12.2.6"` as a dependency, but `npm install` is giving me this error:

```
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@12.2.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^12.2.6" from my-package@2.1.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/pi-diagram
npm ERR!     my-package@"2.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
```

Does `12.2.10` not match `^12.2.6` specification?

Comment: Same here now!!